# Passing a python datastructure to MS R Server model that was deployed in R

Tags: python, microsoft-r

I am running ML server and I have a service deployed that expects one of its inputs to be a data.frame (its a model deployed in R).

I'm using the azureml-model-management-sdk
 https://pypi.org/project/azureml-model-management-sdk/#history

would that be something like :

```
opts = {
         "ntree" :55,
         "mtry" : 0.1,
         "sampleSize" : 0.45
}
```

So in short, the environment has R and python models deployed to ML (R) server. I'm trying to get predictions from both of them in python.

I have also tried

```
opts = {
         "ntree" :[55],
         "mtry" : [0.1],
         "sampleSize" : [0.45]
}
```

Comment: Same answer as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52544689/passing-data-frame-to-ms-r-server-model-operationalisation/52548269#52548269

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing data frame to MS R Server model operationalisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52544689/passing-data-frame-to-ms-r-server-model-operationalisation)

Comment: I'm calling in python and the model was deployed in R. I'm looking to use python datastructures.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is to use a pandas.dataframe.. which I guess isn't clear. I ended up looking at help(service_object) which listed all the inputs , ouputs and types ect.. even the types on the server side.

This opened up the door to a new error, which is a known bug.